# How to have 2 "areas" in python blessed/blessings/ncurses

Tags: python, blessed

I want to be tailing a file and at the same time provide an overlay with keys that can be pressed.

How can I make sure that data will be displayed and updated immediately? I hope it wouldn't have to redraw the keys at the bottom all the time. I also prefer not to have to buffer the tails, but see them immediately.

Basically, the bottom few lines should be reserved for the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Use a csr terminal sequence to change the scroll region. In [Blessed](https://pypi.org/project/blessed) this would be something like:

```
import sys
import blessed

term = blessed.Terminal()
sys.stdout.write(term.move(term.height, 0))
sys.stdout.write(term.clear_eol + 'This text stays put')
sys.stdout.write(term.csr(0, term.height - 3))
sys.stdout.write(term.move(term.height - 3, 0))
for line in range (1, 11):
    print('Reading line %d' % line)
```

Version 2 of Blessed will be released soon and that might change the code a little.

Comment: For anyone wondering what a "csr terminal sequence" is:
Change Scroll Region. Essentially `blessed.Terminal.__getattr__()` [will fall back](https://github.com/jquast/blessed/blob/master/blessed/formatters.py#L481-L484) to [`curses.tigetstr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.tigetstr) capability lookup on otherwise-not-found attributes. This in turn does a [`terminfo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) ([originally included on Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)) capability lookup.